# How to put rectangle into the middle

Tags: html, css

How to put rectangle between triangle? http://goo.gl/EgXE5k When I remove text from rectangle it returns on its normal position. `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float them all left:

```
.left,.center,.right {
        float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ru7zn/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
position: absolute;
```

and then design left and top attributes for each DIV

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ru7zn/4/)

Answer (score 0):

add this to the rectangle:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HMfz7/